# How to extract all sequences mapped to a transcript from Kallisto output

Tags: sam, samtools, kallisto

*This question has also been asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9488897/)*

I ran Kallisto with the --pseudobam option. How do I extract all the short reads that are mapped to a single transcript (e.g. ENST00000367969.8)?  As a person without any previous SAM/BAM experience, I tried the following things without success. Really appreciate some help here.

I first tried:

```
samtools view -S pseudoalignments.bam ENST00000367969.8
```

but got the following error:

```
[E::idx_find_and_load] Could not retrieve index file for 'pseudoalignments.bam'
[main_samview] random alignment retrieval only works for indexed BAM or CRAM files.
```

I tried to index the file using:

```
samtools index pseudoalignments.bam
```

but get the following error:

```
[E::hts_idx_push] NO_COOR reads not in a single block at the end 79729 -1
[E::sam_index] Read 'A00742:184:HLTF2DSXY:4:1101:4417:1000' with ref_name='ENST00000556431.1', ref_length=4142, flags=83, pos=2098 cannot be indexed
samtools index: failed to create index for "pseudoalignments.bam"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the BAM file again with `samtools sort` and then run `samtools index` on the result. That should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[What Devon said.](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/17689/298) Alternatively, you could also just convert the bam to sam and then look for lines where the 3rd field (the reference the sequence is aligned to) is what you want:

```
samtools view pseudoalignments.bam | awk '$3=="ENST00000367969.8"'
```

But really, it's far better to sort and index the file as Devon suggested so  you can use dedicated tools in future.